# Infinite sub-sequences that make up a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ can be broken into sub-sequences, $\{a_n\}^1_{k_1}, \{a_n\}^2_{k_2}, \dots,\{a_n\}^m_{k_m}$, if every element in $\{a_n\}$ belongs to at least one of the sub-sequences.

I had to prove that if all these sub-sequences converge to $L_1, L_2, \dots , L_M$ correspondingly, then these are $all$ the possible partial limits of $\{a_n\}$.

Now, if the number of sub-sequences is finite, there is no problem.
Assume there is another limit, $L\notin \{L_1, L_2, \dots , L_M\}$.

Say $L_1, L_2, \dots , L_M$  are ordered, such that $L_1< L_2< \dots < L_M$. So there is an $1\le i \le m$ such that $L_i<L<L_{i+1}$.

Choose $\epsilon=\frac 1 2 min\{|L_2-L_1|,|L_3-L_2|,\dots, |L-L_i|, |L_{i+1}-L| ,\dots, |L_m-L_{m-1}|\}$.

For every $l$, there exists a $K_l$ such that for every $k>K_l$, $|a_{n_{k_l}}-L_l|<\epsilon$. Choose $N=max\{K_1, K_2, \dots, K_m\}$.

So, for every $n>N$ we get that all the elements of all the sub-sequences are in disjoint surroundings of their limits. There is also an infinite number of elements of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ in the $\epsilon$ surrounding of $L$, since $L$ is a partial limit. But $L$ is in a disjoint surrounding so for $n>N$ there are no elements of the sub-sequences in the $\epsilon$ surrounding of $L$. But by the definition written above, every element of $\{a_n\}$ is found in at least one of the sub-sequences. Contradiction.

But this bothers me - what if there is an infinite number of sub-sequences. Then $L$ might not have an infinite number of elements from some sub-sequence in its $\epsilon$ surrounding, but each sub-sequence could have one element in the $\epsilon$ surrounding of $L$, and still $L$ can be a partial limit of $\{a_n\}$ since there is an infinite number of elements in its surrounding.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result does not hold in general when the given family of subsequences is infinite.

For each positive integer $n$ there is a unique pair $\langle k,m\rangle$ of non-negative integers such that $n=2^k(2m+1)$. Define a sequence $\sigma=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ by setting

$$a_{2^k(2m+1)}=\begin{cases}
-1,&\text{if }m\le k\\
k,&\text{if }m>k\;.
\end{cases}$$

For each $k\in\Bbb N$ the subsequence $\sigma_k=\langle a_{2^k(2m+1)}:m\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $k$, and every term of $\sigma$ is in exactly one of the subsequences $\sigma_k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$. Thus, the set of limits of these subsequences is precisely $\Bbb N$. However, each term of the subsequence $\langle a_{2^k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of terms $a_{2^k(2m+1)}$ for which $m=0$ is $-1$, so this subsequence converges to $-1\notin\Bbb N$.